# "Example where" or "example in which"

Tags: word-choice, where-which

I think both are correct but is that true and what is the difference between them (if there is any)?

> This is an example **where** you can see that...
>
> This is an example **in which** you can see that...

or in a question

> Can you give an example **where** A is the opposite to B?
>
> Can you give an example **in which** A is the opposite to B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your audience expects formal grammar, use a “which” construction. If your audience is more relaxed, you can use “where.” However both are grammatically correct: in the two sentences you have mentioned, the words “which” and “where” both function as relative pronouns. Relative pronouns (*which* and *where*) introduce the dependent clauses you have cited (*you can see that...* and *A is the opposite to B*).

Comment: Just for clarification: do you mean that any subclause starting with "which" or "where" has an implicit "you can see that..." after the pronoun?

Comment: @Raku - Nope. I was referrig to Em1's question and his examples.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad then >_<.